# How to get the maximum value of an element from entire database in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to get the Maximum value of `<ID>`from all the documents present inside the database.

Sample Document-

```
<root>
   <ID>3253523</ID>
   <value1>.....</value1>
   <value2>.....</value2>
   <value3>.....</value3>
   <value4>.....</value4>
    .....................
</root>
```

My database is having more than **1 million** records and i want to fetch the ID which is having greatest value among all.

I can't use `fn:last()` because it won't give me the maximum value.

I need to use that value to create an INCREMENTAL COUNTER (The Maximum value will become my first value to the COUNTER).

Any Suggestions to fetch that value in an efficient way ? Because i can't do a `cts:search()` over **1 million** records and then do `orderby ascending` and fetch the last value.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an element range index to the `ID` element then use the [`cts:values`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values) function to retrieve the first of the indexed values in descending order.

Example:

```
(: assuming a path range index for an int scalar at path '/root/ID' :)
for $i in 1 to 100
  let $doc := <root><ID>{$i}</ID></root>
  return
    xdmp:document-insert("/test/doc-" || $i, $doc, (), "test");

(cts:values(cts:path-reference("/root/ID"), (), "descending"))[1]
```

Comment: @Elijah-- Thank you for responding. I am trying to use something like this-cts:values(cts:path-reference('/root/ID'),1, "descending"). Created a path range index for ID. But it seems something wrong i doing. Can you please suggest me the same.

Comment: @Shalini I updated the answer to include an example. Perhaps change the second argument from "1" to an empty sequence?

Comment: Thanks Elijah ! The example you have given works well for me. But when i tried same with my case it is returning me an empty sequence. My Path range index is like /root/somevalue/somevalue/ID and it is having name space "example.com/somevalue". I have created path namespace on the admin page as well as the path range index with '/root/somevalue/somevalue/ID' but for some reason it is giving me empty sequence.

Comment: @Shalini could you post another stackoverflow question detailing your path range setup, document structure, and the cts:values query? I'd need more details to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Elijah-- Sure i will do it. Thanks

Comment: @Elijah-- Posted a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you need to get the max, or some other aggregate of an element containing date, price, number, or other kind of value, the answer from Elijah is adequate.

For the specific case of sequential numbers, there is a bit more to it. How to guarantee uniqueness across threads when you have parallel ingestion? It is a non-trivial problem, and we typically recommend against using sequential numbers for performance reasons because of that. Use random numbers instead. It makes collision practically impossible, and prevents contention to derive the max + 1 ID.

I've created a library that allows various ways of generating unique identifiers, and elaborates on the pros and cons of each:

https://github.com/grtjn/ml-unique#how-it-works

HTH!

Comment: @grtjn-- Thank you for your response. I will go thorugh the ways which you have implemented. For importing module "uniq" i should install the mlpm first to my local server from GitHub ?

Comment: mlpm can be installed from npm registry. It can be handy to fetch and deploy the ml-unique package, but it is not a requirement. There is no compilation, so you could also just drop unique.xqy in your modules database with some other tool.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @grtjn-- I am trying to use `uniq:next-sequential-uri`. Can you please tell me how should i set a `seed` value or `initial counter start` value in that function ?

Comment: No need for seed, nor initial counter, it will start with 1 automatically..